# OpenXml (.net): SimpleField is not formated

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I tried to create a word document with page number in Header. I used SimpleField to insert Page number and page count.
But, these fields are not impacted by Color and font size defined in the RunProperties, unlike the text (as it's showed in the picture below).

How to format SimpleField??

Thanks

[image: Word document]

```
    private static void CreateReport(string filename)
    {
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
        {

            using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
            {
                // Add a main document part. 
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                // Create the document structure
                mainPart.Document = new Document();
                mainPart.Document.Body = new Body();

                //Create paragraph for header
                var paragraph = new Paragraph();

                var run = paragraph.AppendChild(new Run());
                run.Append(new RunProperties()
                {
                    Bold = new Bold(),
                    FontSize = new FontSize() { Val = "48" },
                    Color = new Color() { Val = "FF0000" /*red*/ }
                }
                    );
                run.Append(new Text() { Text = "Page:" });
                run.Append(new SimpleField() { Instruction = @"PAGE" });
                run.Append(new Text() { Text = "/" });
                run.Append(new SimpleField() { Instruction = @"SECTIONPAGES" });

                //Add paragraph to header
                AddParagraphToHeader(mainPart, paragraph);

                //Save document
                wordDocument.SaveAs(filename);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void AddParagraphToHeader(MainDocumentPart mainPart, Paragraph paragraph)
    {
        var part = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();

        var header = new Header() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
        header.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

        paragraph.RsidParagraphAddition = "00164C17";
        paragraph.RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00164C17";
        header.Append(paragraph);
        part.Header = header;

        var headerPartId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(part);
        mainPart.Document.PrependChild<HeaderReference>((new HeaderReference() { Id = headerPartId }));
    }
```

Comment: I've never tried this in the Open XML, but in the UI, in order to force a field result to pick up the formatting applied to the first character (the field code bracket `}`) it requires the `\* CharFormat` switch. The resulting field code would look like: `{ PAGE \* CharFormat }` I assume, therefore, that `Instruction` would need to be assigned: `@"PAGE \* CharFormat"`

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

After fighting with this, I found a solution that works for me -- `SimpleField` is the wrong thing to use for this scenario, you need to end up with a `w:instrText` by generating `FieldChar` and `FieldCode` objects, which means your code needs to be something like this:

```
Run PageNumRun = new Run(
    new Text() { Text = "PAGE ", Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve },
    new FieldChar { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.Begin },
    new FieldCode("PAGE"), // This is the "Instruction" from the SimpleField
    new FieldChar { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.End },
    new Text() { Text = " OF ", Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve },
    new FieldChar { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.Begin },
    new FieldCode("NUMPAGES"), // This is the "Instruction" from the SimpleField
    new FieldChar { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.End }
);
```

This will honor your `Run` font characteristics for the automatically generated values.